# Передача содержимого текстового файла в TextBox

Tags: winforms, c++

Привет всем.

У меня такой вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы на нажатие кнопки открывалось окно обзора файлов и при выборе текстового файла его содержание появлялося в TextBOX1?

Код для обзора файлов

```
 // Create a new OpenFileDialog and display it.
 OpenFileDialog^ fd = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
 fd->DefaultExt = "*.";
 fd->ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

я делаю так, но содержимое файла бросаю не в textBox, а в richTextBox, он для этого и служит как бы

```
void ToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files|*.txt";
            if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                 richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            }
        }
```